# Creating a new column in a data frame by mapping multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, mapping

I want to map one column of dataframe to another dataframe by using multiple columns.
The sample dataframes are as follow:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['Date'] = ['2018-08-10','2018-08-10','2018-08-10','2018-08-10','2018-08-10',
               '2018-08-11','2018-08-11','2018-08-11','2018-08-12','2018-08-12',
               '2018-08-13','2018-08-12','2018-08-12','2018-08-12','2018-08-12']
df1['Name'] = ['A','A','A','A','A',
              'B','B','B','C','C',
              'D','D','E','F','F']
df1 ['Orgz'] = ['Alpha','Alpha','Alpha','Alpha','Alpha',
               'Beta','Beta','Beta','Gamma','Gamma',
               'Theta','Theta','Theta','Theta','Theta']
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['Date'] = ['2018-08-10','2018-08-11','2018-08-12','2018-08-12','2018-08-13','2018-08-12','2018-08-12']
df2['Name'] = ['A','B','C','D','D','E','F']
df2 ['Orgz']= ['Alpha','Beta','Gamma','Theta','Theta','Theta','Theta']
df2 ['min'] = [60,85,90,77,25,20,30]
```

I want to map the column df2.min to df1 by creating a new column.
However, I have three common columns which are Date, Name and Orgz to Map.
In this case, I cannot just use Name to map it as there will be the same name at different date in my actual database.
So I decided to use  three columns (Date,Orgz and Name) to map with df2.
The result will be assinged to a new column in df1.
My actual result will look like as follow:

[image]

From the results, you will notice that some of the name are multiple at the same date. in that case, I just want to map the min value on the first row, the rest of the row are set to 0.

How can I do it?

Thanks,
Zep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join and then set `0` by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with boolean mask created by [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on=['Date','Name','Orgz'], how='left')
df3['min'] = np.where(df3.duplicated(subset=['Date','Name','Orgz']), 0, df3['min'])
print (df3)
          Date Name   Orgz  min
0   2018-08-10    A  Alpha   60
1   2018-08-10    A  Alpha    0
2   2018-08-10    A  Alpha    0
3   2018-08-10    A  Alpha    0
4   2018-08-10    A  Alpha    0
5   2018-08-11    B   Beta   85
6   2018-08-11    B   Beta    0
7   2018-08-11    B   Beta    0
8   2018-08-12    C  Gamma   90
9   2018-08-12    C  Gamma    0
10  2018-08-13    D  Theta   77
11  2018-08-13    D  Theta    0
12  2018-08-12    E  Theta   25
13  2018-08-12    F  Theta   30
14  2018-08-12    F  Theta    0
```

Comment: Hi Jez,
Thanks a lot. Appreciated your help.

Comment: When I applied the same concept to my actual data, it showed key error

Comment: @Zephyr - keyerror means there are different columns names, check it.

Comment: Yeah checking now